# Appium , not able to read text having content desc and index on an Android native app

Tags: java, android, selenium, xpath, appium

I am using Appium version (1.4) on an Native android app

[image]

I want to read the text show in red box.
I am not able to locate the element based on content-desc and index too.

These are some of the code which I have tried but its failing to locate it.

1. Parent child select based on index

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@index='2']/android.view.View[@index='0']"))
   ```
2. using class and content-desc

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@content-desc='Your balance is: 100.00$ ']")).click();
   ```
3. Using class and iterating through a list

   ```
   List<WebElement> arrayOfProperties2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.view.View"));
   System.out.println("Found arrayOfProperties2 total: "+ arrayOfProperties2.size());
   ```

The size of the list comes zero in this case.

***The scenario is to read the text shown since the balance amount changes .***

I am able to locate other elements on the activity but not the above one.

Answer (score 2):

try by using the below xpath:

```
//*[@class = 'android.view.View' and contains(@content-desc,'Your balance is')]
```

hope this will help you and let me know what happens.

Answer (score -1):

It would be fairly easy using [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient).

Start [Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI) using

```
culebra --use-regexps --gui
```

and the generated script will contain a line like

```
no_id25 = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise(re.compile(u'''Your balance is: 100.00$ Heading'''))
```

change it to a more suitable regex

```
no_id25 = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise(re.compile(u'''Your balance is: \d+.\d+\$ Heading'''))
```

and it should match your View.

Strictly speaking, if you are not going to interact and just want to match the View you may run it without `--gui`.

Comment: You might want to mention that the the solution you link to is yours.